# How can I emulate the behavior of the python2 print statement in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, printing

Sometimes I am putting together some quick code and have long or parentheses-enclosed expressions. I want to be able to print them quickly and easily with no other fancy stuff or `**kwargs`. I would like to be able to use the `print` keyword as in python2 for such usage. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack that uses operator overloading with which you could at least emulate the print keyword to some extent.

If you were to write a class and overload any of its `operator(a,b)` methods, you would be able to write anything you wanted in the method body and pass some value as an RHS to the operator, mathematically speaking. For example, here's a class:

```
class printkw:
    def __lshift__(self, value=None):
        print(value)
        return value
```

Then if you do something like

```
printk = printkw()
printk << "hello world"
```

then it would produce the output

```
hello world
```

If you wanted to treat it totally anonymously, you could get away with

```
printkw() << "hello world"
```

although it looks much more unaesthetic now.

The operator you choose to overload can be anything; even the `=` assignment operator, however, I personally prefer the lshift operator because it makes it look similar to C++. Also, the assignment operator doesn't make semantic sense: you don't assign something you want to output. However, it's really up to your preference.

Of course, this is what I already called it, a *hack*, and will probably be frowned upon. Certainly, I do not use such a hack too often (only about twice till now, to be honest), and do not recommend it either. However, sometimes you just have very long statements, or sometimes you want to debug and write something quick and dirty and having to parenthesize the expression properly can be tedious, which is when I use this hack. For regular use, please avoid using it as it may break printing where others expect it to be the standard `print()` function but you have instead used the above-mentioned keyword emulation.

Comment: You can do something even more sneaky which is to use the `type` definition for a class: `out = type("debugger", (object,), {"__lshift__": (lambda _, v: print(v))})(); out << "Hello world!"`

Comment: Update: `out = type("",(),{"__lshift__":(lambda _,v:print(v)or _)})()` is probably the shortest you can go with this and allows for chaining like `out << 1 << 2` and printing expressions containing more "superior" operations through doing something like `out <<= 1 == 2` (`==` is more superior as in normally, `out << 1` would be evaluated first if not for the `<<=` being used instead)